Run tests without database auto configuration
In the test I want to send a request and validate the response payload. I want to do the entire flow Request -> ReaderController -> ReaderService -> ReaderRepository and back. Here, I don't want the repository to hit the database, but mock the repository function to return the value I want.
So far I have this code below. I have disabled the Hibernate configurer to stop the test service trying to connect to the actual postgresql instance at http://localhost:5432. Without the HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration exclude, test will fail due to connection failure to http://localhost:5432.
@SpringBootTest
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
    HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class
})
public class ReaderControllerTest {

  @MockBean
  private ReaderRepository readerRepository;

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Test
  void createUserTest() throws Exception {
    var newReader = new Reader();
    newReader.setName("user");
    newReader.setEmail("user@email.com");

    Mockito.when(readerRepository.save(null)).thenReturn(newReader);

    mockMvc
        .perform(
            post("/user").contentType("application/json").content("{\"name\": \"test\"}"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());
  }
}

However, above code also fails because bean for ReaderRepository not found since I disabled HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.
Error creating bean with name 'bookController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'bookService': Error creating bean with name 'bookServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'bookRepository': Error creating bean with name 'bookRepository' defined in com.example.demo.repository.BookRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManager'

@MockBean in the test for ReaderRepository does not have any effect apparently.
@MockBean
private ReaderRepository readerRepository;

I want test to be light and run as fast as possible so I don't want incorporate Testcontainer.

Found a solution. @AutoConfigureTestDatabase(connection = EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.NONE) Disables the database configuration.
Here is the complete solution.
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(connection = EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.NONE)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ReaderControllerTest {
  @MockBean
  private ReaderRepository readerRepository;

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Test
  void createReaderTest() throws Exception {
    var reader = ReaderData.getReader();

    when(readerRepository.findByEmail(anyString())).thenReturn(Optional.empty());
    when(readerRepository.save(null)).thenReturn(reader);

    var json = """
        { "name": "%s", "email": "%s" }
        """.formatted(reader.getName(), reader.getEmail());

    mockMvc
        .perform(
            post("/user").contentType("application/json").content(json))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());
  }
}

